# Find duration only with ffprobe in Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, script, command-line, ffprobe

I want to find video file duration only with [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) but

```
ffprobe FILENAME.EXT 2| find "Duration:"
```

does not filter output to show just the line with **"Duration:"**  Instead, I got:

> Argument '2' provided as input filename, but 'FILENAME.MP4' was
> already specified.

How do I see just the duration of a file from the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you just want information about a file, you should probably use "ffprobe", not "ffmpeg". Otherwise you'll get an answer, but you'll also have an error return status.

As to your real question: By convention, ffmpeg reserves STDOUT for binary video and audio data *only*. Everything else, including all the possible kinds of informative text, is sent to STDERR.

So, try changing your code to:

`ffprobe FILENAME.EXT 2| find "Duration:"`  (for a *nix shell)

or

`ffprobe.exe FILENAME.EXT 2>&1 | findstr Duration` (for a Windows shell)

Comment: Does not work. See revised question.

Comment: Improved it. Thank you